# Cannot connect to docker container from within WSL2

Tags: docker

I am a docker newbie and this is a newbie question :)
I am running Docker Engine from Ubuntu 18.04 in WLS2. When I run my container, I cannot connect to it from a WSL2 bash.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.4-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/#creating-a-dockerfile
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "./src/main.js" ]
```

This is how I (successfully) build my image out of it

```
 docker build . -t gb/test
```

This is how I run my container

```
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 --name gbtest gb/test

# tried also this one with no luck
#docker run --rm -P --name gbtest gb/test
```

My server starts successfully, but I cannot understand how to reach it via curl. I tried all of the following with no success

```
curl http://localhost:3000
curl http://127.0.01:3000
curl http://127.17.01:3000 <- gather with ifconfig
```

I tried also what suggested by [> this <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) answer, but it didn't work.

```
# start container with --add-host
docker run --rm -p 3000:3000 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway --name gbtest gb/test

# try to connect with that host
curl http://host.docker.internal:3000
```

Note that the NodeJS server I am developing is connecting to the right port as:

- it states in its output that it connects to `http://127.0.0.1:3000`
- when I run it directly, so without docker, I can connect with just `curl http://localhost:3000`

Should you need any further info, just let me know.

EDIT 1

Here is my main.js file, basically the base example from Fastify.

```
import Fastify from "fastify";

// Require the framework and instantiate it
const fastify = Fastify({ logger: true });

// Declare a route
fastify.get("/", async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: "world" };
});

// Run the server!
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port: 3000 });
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();
```

Here are my container logs

```
$ docker logs gbtest
{"level":30,"time":1655812753498,"pid":1,"hostname":"8429b2ed314d","msg":"Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:3000"}
```

I also tried to use `host` network like below. It works, but I am not sure it is the way to go. How am I supposed to expose a container to the internet? Is it OK to share the whole host network? Does it come with any security concerns?

```
docker run --rm --network host --name gbtest gb/test
```

Comment: What's actually in `src/main.js`?  "It states in its output ... `http://127.0.0.1`" is a bad sign actually; do you have something like an `app.listen()` call that binds to only the container-private localhost interface?

Comment: Output of `docker logs gbtest` ?

Comment: I edited the question with the info you asked for

Comment: @DavidMaze so the issue could be in the ```fastify.listen({ port: 3000 })``` line?

Comment: I'm not familiar with fastify, but if you can specify a host, and the default host is localhost, you would need to set it to the container name or `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `await fastify.listen({ port: 3000 });` to `await fastify.listen({ host: "0.0.0.0", port: 3000 });` did the trick.

As you guys pointed out, I was binding to container-private localhost by default, while I want my container to respond to outer connections.

New output of `docker logs gbtest` is

```
{"level":30,"time":1655813850993,"pid":1,"hostname":"8e2460ac00c5","msg":"Server listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000"}
```